# Slicing?? an appended list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if something was possible or if I am going about it in the wrong way.

I have a if statement which is checking an external file for criteria. It then displays the results (all this works). Using 2 of the figures displayed from the results I need to calculate an amount and print this next to the results for each record displayed.

What I desire: to print each item from the appended list 1 at a time e.g. when record 1 is printed it display item 1 of calc, record 2 prints, it displays item 2 of calc.

`numberofItems` and `Data` are from other code within my program which is splitting, appending and sort my .txt file.

```
def opt():
    calc = []

    for i in range (numberOfItems):
        nextRecord = Data[i]
        no1 = (nextRecord[0])
        date = (nextRecord[1])
        no2 = (nextRecord[2])
        no3 = int(nextRecord[3])
        rank = (nextRecord[4])
        no4 = int(nextRecord[5])

        if no4 < no3:
            calc.append(no4 - no3)
            print (no1, "\t\t\t", no2, "\t\t", no3, "\t\t", no4, "\t\t", calc)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does `Brows` have to do with your issue? What's `Data`? What's `numberOfItems? What are `a`and `b`? What's a set one? What's actually the desired output? Please read [ask].

Comment: Also don't you have an indentation issue ? Isn't your `if` statement supposed to be indented in order to be within the `for` loop ?

Comment: Edited my code/ post. Copying issues/ errors within it.

Comment: As you ask ... you're probably going about it the wrong way. For i in range(#items): then using i as an index into a_vector is very unpythonic. You probably want to use for thing in a_vector: and then work directly with thing.

Comment: I thought it would have been something quite simple e.g. calc[0:1] displays item number one etc. is there no way to just make that increase each time?

Comment: I still can't seem to work it out. I've searched about ranges and printing from lists but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working about your code?

Comment: The line which has calc printed at the end does not print the 1 calc for the record which is displaying. It displays the first one for the first record, the first and second for the 2nd record and so forth. I only want it to display the calc for that record.

Comment: Looks like you just want to print no4 - no3, but I guess you would be just doing it if that were the case...

Comment: I have to sum all the values later so need to store them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't want to have `calc` at the end of your `print` call on the last line, but rather, you want to print the item you just appended to `calc` on the previous line.

The most obvious way to do this is to simply recalculate the value when you want to print it:

```
print(no1, "\t\t\t", no2, "\t\t", no3, "\t\t", no4, "\t\t", no4 - no3)
```

Alternatively, you could save the calculation as a variable before appending and printing it (this would make more sense if the calculation was expensive, it doesn't really matter for subtracting two integers):

```
val = no4 - no3
calc.append(val)
print(no1, "\t\t\t", no2, "\t\t", no3, "\t\t", no4, "\t\t", val)
```

A last option is to take the value back from the `calc` list. You can do this by indexing `calc` with `-1` to get the last item in the list. This is what you're specifically asking for, but there's not much reason to do things this way:

```
print(no1, "\t\t\t", no2, "\t\t", no3, "\t\t", no4, "\t\t", calc[-1])
```